# Non-Numeric Ttest?

Tags: statistics

What is a statistical test you can use to determine a relationship between two groups that are non-numeric (i.e. looking for the equivalent of a ttest for non-numeric data).

Specifically, I am looking to compare data of plant growth. I want to compare the type of plant (non-numeric) to CO2 uptake (numeric) and determine if there is a statistical association.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a little confusing, so to make progress I'll assume you mean you want to compare CO2 uptake for different kinds of plants. (If that's not it, you'll have to clarify.) This is a classic group comparison problem, for which the t-test was invented: you want to know (I assume) whether the mean CO2 uptake differs from group to group. So, this is a problem usually handled with a t-test. That said, you might consider a Bayesian approach. I can spell it out if you are interested.

Comment: This probably belongs on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) . The question is admittedly confusing.  If numeric CO2 uptake is your **response** variable ("dependent"), then you can use a regular t-test.  If you want CO2 uptake to be a **predictor** variable of plant type, you can use logistic regression.  But unless you already know what technique you want to use and are having trouble programming it, this is a statistical (CV) and not programming (SO) question.